# one Android app has two same process

Tags: android, process

My application is running, but at a certain moment, another process which has same name of the process start running.In other words,one app has two same process, this situation is how to produce, how should avoid it?

ps

u0_a29 6706  7316 1468652 49584 00000000 b75ac452 R com.ucreator.yiweimai

u0_a29 7316  156 1469668 78772 ffffffff b75ae921 S com.ucreator.yiweimai

u0_a29 7362  156 935332 50812 ffffffff b75ae617 S com.ucreator.yiweimai:pushcore

u0_a29 13924 156 943784 42376 ffffffff b75ae617 S        com.ucreator.yiweimai:pushservice

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ucreator.yiweimai"
    android:versionCode="800"
    android:versionName="6.8.8">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_PACKAGE_SIZE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />

    <!-- 云巴 权限 开始 -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_USER_PRESENT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <!-- 云巴 权限 结束 -->

    <!-- 在SDCard中创建与删除文件权限 -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
    <!-- 往SDCard写入数据权限 -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- 个推SDK权限配置开始 -->
    <!-- 自定义权限 -->
    <uses-permission android:name="getui.permission.GetuiService.com.ucreator.yiweimai" />
    <!-- 替换为第三方应用的包名 -->
    <permission
        android:name="getui.permission.GetuiService.com.ucreator.yiweimai"
        android:protectionLevel="normal" />

    <application
        android:name="com.hn.ucreater.ws.base.WXApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">

        <!-- 主界面 -->

        <activity
            android:name="com.hn.ucreater.ws.func.main.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.hn.ucreater.ws.func.service.MainService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
                <action android:name="action_service_init" />
                <action android:name="action_service_timer" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="com.hn.ucreater.ws.func.service.SyncDataService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
                <action android:name="action_service_sync_wx" />
                <action android:name="action_service_check_back" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.hn.ucreater.ws.func.service.CheckAppStatuService" />
        <service android:name="com.hn.ucreater.ws.func.service.HandleOrderService" />
        <service android:name="com.hn.ucreater.ws.func.service.UpdateSyncDataService" />
        <service android:name="com.hn.ucreater.ws.func.service.GetGroupMemberSnsService" />
        <service android:name="com.hn.ucreater.ws.func.main.WeiXinFloat" />
        <service android:name="com.hn.ucreater.ws.func.service.JpushGetInfoService" />
        <service
            android:name="com.hn.ucreater.ws.func.service.FloatService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
                <action android:name="ACTION_START_FLOAT_SERVICE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="com.hn.ucreater.ws.func.service.CheckMemberShipService"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service android:name="com.hn.ucreater.ws.func.service.HandleVideoAndEmojiService" />
        <service android:name="com.hn.ucreater.ws.func.service.CheckTrialChatRoomServices" />
        <service android:name="com.hn.ucreater.ws.func.service.CheckCardOrderService" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.hn.ucreater.ws.func.receiver.StartServiceReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:priority="1000">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.hn.ucreater.ws.transport.remote2local.alarm" />
                <action android:name="com.hn.ucreater.ws.func.service.handle_order_service" />
                <action android:name="com.hn.ucreater.ws.func.service.set_alarms" />
                <action android:name="com.hn.ucreater.ws.func.service.get_sns_service" />
                <action android:name="com.hn.ucreater.ws.func.service.check_fail_msg_service" />
                <action android:name="com.hn.ucreater.ws.func.service.check_back_service" />
                <action android:name="com.hn.ucreater.ws.func.service.check_creater_friend" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.hn.ucreater.ws.func.receiver.AppInstallReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />

                <data android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.hn.ucreater.ws.func.receiver.WifiStateReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- 个推SDK配置开始 -->
        <!-- 配置的第三方参数属性 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="PUSH_APPID"
            android:value="5e0fF3mZKE87awYn6pyFT4" /> <!-- 替换为第三方应用的APPID -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="PUSH_APPKEY"
            android:value="EnWfQvWruR9HVEFItnuA55" /> <!-- 替换为第三方应用的APPKEY -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="PUSH_APPSECRET"
            android:value="NZe4R3NaPi5galLDriVuW6" /> <!-- 替换为第三方应用的APPSECRET -->
        <!-- 配置SDK核⼼服务⽤来接收各种消息和命令回复, ⽤户⾃定义服务继承 GTIntentService -->
        <service android:name="com.hn.ucreater.ws.func.service.Ge1Tui1OrderService" />
        <!-- 配置SDK核心服务 -->
        <service
            android:name="com.hn.ucreater.ws.func.service.Ge1Tui1PushService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="NotificationCenterUser"
            android:process=":pushservice" />

        <receiver android:name="com.igexin.sdk.PushReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                <action android:name="com.igexin.sdk.action.refreshls" />
                <!-- 以下三项为可选的action声明，可大大提高service存活率和消息到达速度 -->
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!-- <activity -->
        <!-- android:name="com.igexin.sdk.PushActivity" -->
        <!-- android:excludeFromRecents="true" -->
        <!-- android:exported="false" -->
        <!-- android:process=":pushservice" -->
        <!-- android:taskAffinity="com.igexin.sdk.PushActivityTask" -->
        <!-- android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/> -->
        <!-- <activity -->
        <!-- android:name="com.igexin.sdk.GActivity" -->
        <!-- android:excludeFromRecents="true" -->
        <!-- android:exported="true" -->
        <!-- android:process=":pushservice" -->
        <!-- android:taskAffinity="com.igexin.sdk.PushActivityTask" -->
        <!-- android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/> -->
        <service
            android:name="com.igexin.download.DownloadService"
            android:process=":pushservice" />

        <receiver android:name="com.igexin.download.DownloadReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <provider
            android:name="com.igexin.download.DownloadProvider"
            android:authorities="downloads.com.ucreator.yiweimai"
            android:exported="true"
            android:process=":pushservice" /> <!-- 替换为第三方应用的包名 -->
        <!-- 个推SDK配置结束 -->


        <!-- JPsh Receiver -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.hn.ucreater.ws.func.receiver.OrderReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="cn.jpush.android.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <action android:name="cn.jpush.android.intent.MESSAGE_RECEIVED" />
                <action android:name="cn.jpush.android.intent.NOTIFICATION_RECEIVED" />
                <action android:name="cn.jpush.android.intent.NOTIFICATION_OPENED" />
                <action android:name="cn.jpush.android.intent.CONNECTION" />

                <category android:name="com.ucreator.yiweimai" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.hn.ucreater.ws.func.service.SendSnsContentService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />
        <service
            android:name="com.hn.ucreater.ws.func.service.CheckFailMsgService"
            android:exported="false"></service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="YUNBA_APPKEY"
            android:value="5819891349af2025217d2944" />

        <receiver android:name="com.hn.ucreater.ws.func.receiver.YunBaReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="io.yunba.android.PUBLISH_RECEIVED_ACTION" />
                <action android:name="io.yunba.android.SUBSCRIBE_RECEIVED_ACTION" />
                <action android:name="io.yunba.android.MESSAGE_RECEIVED_ACTION" />
                <action android:name="io.yunba.android.PRESENCE_RECEIVED_ACTION" />
                <action android:name="io.yunba.android.MESSAGE_CONNECTED_ACTION" />
                <action android:name="io.yunba.android.MESSAGE_DISCONNECTED_ACTION" />

                <category android:name="com.ucreator.yiweimai" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="io.yunba.android.core.YunBaReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="io.yunba.android.core.YunBaService"
            android:exported="true" />

        <service
            android:name="com.hn.ucreater.ws.func.accessibility.AutoLoginWXService"
            android:label="@string/accessibility_service_label"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
                android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_config_auto_login_wx" />
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="com.hn.ucreater.ws.func.accessibility.HandleEventIntentService"
            android:exported="false"></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What actions cause this?

Comment: This application running on android 4.2.2

Comment: What does the user do that causes the multiple processes to start?

Comment: This app is a service,no activity, bind another app's service,two process cause two callback.

Comment: What causes the service to start? Do you have a BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: could you please post your AndriodManifest.xml?

Comment: @lelloman how to post my AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: at the bottom of your question on the left you should see "share", "edit", "close".. click "edit" and copy paste the content of AndroidManifest.xml file